# Joda Time & parsing two digit year correctly based on pivot

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, 2-digit-year

I have the following (somewhat abbreviated) code to parse `String` input into a Joda Time [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object. I need to properly handle multiple formats, including four & two digit years.

```
setupValidDateFormats();
DateTime date = convertToDateTime(thisField.getText());
if (date != null) {
    thisField.setText(date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid date");
}

private void setupValidDateFormats() {
    DateTimeParser[] formats = {
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yy").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yy").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMddyyyy").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMddyy").getParser()
    };
    formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(null, formats).appendTwoDigitYear(1950, true).toFormatter()
            .withLocale(Locale.US);
}

private DateTime convertToDateTime(String input) {
    if (isNullOrEmpty(input)) {
        return null;
    }

    DateTime date;
    try {
        // When you parse a date, it'll throw an exception for not only invalid formats,
        // but for invalid values such as 09/31/2013 or 02/30/2013. Leap year is included as well.
        date = formatter.parseDateTime(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // User input a date in the incorrect format, or an invalid value.
        // Example: 02/30/2013 is invalid.
        date = null;
    }

    return date;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when the user enters `120100`, I expect it to be able to parse correctly and ultimately output at 12/01/1900. However, `formatter.parseDateTime(input);` in `convertToDateTime` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` instead, and the method returns `null`.

Probably worth noting that if I remove the [`appendTwoDigitYear`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendTwoDigitYear%28int%29) from the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) chain, the input does parse successfully, but `120100` becomes `12/01/0000`, but that's not what I need.

Am I misunderstanding the Joda Time API? Shouldn't [`appendTwoDigitYear`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendTwoDigitYear%28int%29) with the 1950 pivot handle the 00 two year digit as 1900?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a pattern like

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMddyyyy")
```

it can read a date like `"120100"`. What it does is read the `12` for `MM`, the `01` for `dd`, and [`00` as a literal value for `yyyy`, ie. `0` starting at year `0`, so `0000`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Because that pattern appears before the `MMddyy` in your `parsers` array, it will be used to parse your date string.

What you'll want to do, along with reordering or removing that format, is use a pivot year.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "120100";

    DateTimeParser[] formats = {
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yy").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yy").getParser(),
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMddyy").getParser()
    };

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(null, formats).toFormatter()
            .withPivotYear(1950).withLocale(Locale.US);

    DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(str);
    System.out.println(dateTime);       
}
```

prints

```
1900-12-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
```

I'm still trying to figure out how `appendTwoDigitYear` works.