# Setting default year in Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I am currently using the [joda dateTime Api](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) in my application. I am using the following code to parse multiple formats of dates into one single format. I am having trouble though when the format does not have a year. currently it sets the year as "2000".

Is there a way to set the year to a default if it is missing?

```
private static final DateTimeParser[] parsers = {
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z").getParser(),
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").getParser(),
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("[dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z]").getParser(),
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").getParser(),
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS").getParser()
 };

 public static DateTime ConvertDate(String timestamp) {

   DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(null, parsers).toFormatter();

   DateTime date = formatter.parseDateTime(timestamp);
   return date;
}
```

example:
`Mar-07 13:59:13,219`

becomes
`2000-03-07T12:59:13.219-07:00`

what I want :

example:
`Mar-07 13:59:13,219`

becomes
`(currentyear)-03-07T12:59:13.219-07:00`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [withDefaultYear()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withDefaultYear%28int%29):

```
public static DateTime convertDate(String timestamp) {

  int stdYear = 1970; // example for new default year

  DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(null, parsers).toFormatter()
    .withDefaultYear(stdYear);

  return formatter.parseDateTime(timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Joda 2.0 the default year is 2000 so that Feb 29 could be parsed correctly, check [this](http://ehc.ac/p/joda-time/bugs/148/).

Not sure if you can change that (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939939/parsing-date-by-multiple-formats-with-pivotyear-set-up-for-2-digit-years) with pivotYear), but as a bypass solution I would add current year to my timestamp if there wasn't any.